# Ratio of two segments of a side of equilateral triangle

Tags: geometry

A line goes through the center (the point in which the 3 medians, bisectors and heights intersect) of an equilateral triangle and is parallel to one of the sides and splits the other two sides. What is the ratio of the two new segments of one of the sides?

Couldn't find any answers on the internet and I'm hard stuck.

[image: figure]

Comment: What is the center of an equilateral triangle? You mean the barycenter?

Comment: the point in which the 3 medians, bisectors and heights intersect

Comment: Add these informations with your question

Comment: @Dude All the centers of an equilateral triangle coincide.

Comment: Do you know about similarity of triangles? Or the fact that centroid divides median in 2:1 ratio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: take advantage of symmetry.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Consider equilateral $ABC$. The centroid divides median $AD$ in the ratio $2:1$. Say $O$ is the center and $E$ is the point where the constructed line meets $AC$. Using similarity of $\triangle AOE$ and $\triangle ADC$, we get $$\frac{AE}{EC} = 2$$ as well.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: label the base vertices of the triangle as $A,B$ and the tip vertex as $C$.  Label the midpoint of $\overline AB$ as $M$ and the center of the triangle as $O$.

Then  $\frac yx = \frac {CO}{CM}$

Then $AO=BO=CO$ and $m\angle OAM = m\angle OAC =m\angle OBM=m\angle OBC \frac 12*60 =30$ and if you extend $CM$ is perpendicular to $AM$. And we have $\triangle OAM\cong \triangle OBM$ which are $30-60-90$ triangles.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have come up with something...

Since its given that the triangle is an equilateral triangle, all the centers will coincide.
Also the median and altitude of the triangle will coincide.
[image]

Consider the $\triangle$ BED, Since ED||AC, $\triangle$ BED is also an equilateral Triangle.

Now $\triangle$ BED$\sim$ $\triangle$ BCA by AAA(all equilateral triangles are similar)

Also we have triangle $\triangle$ BFD$\sim$$\triangle$ BGA (again by AAA)

Thus we have,

$\Rightarrow \frac{BD}{BA} = \frac{BF}{BG} = \frac{FD}{GA} $

Since F is the centroid of ABC we have  $\frac{BF}{FG} = \frac{2}{1}$ or $\frac{BF}{FG} = \frac{2}{3}$

$\Rightarrow \frac{BD}{BA} = \frac{BF}{BG} = \frac{2}{3} $

$\therefore$  $\frac{BD}{DA} =  \frac{BE}{EC} =  \frac{2}{1}$

I hope this helped you ..